# Bootstrap's clearfix doesn't work inside tables

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-float

I'm working with a complex table that eventually gets a form inside a row which uses the Bootstrap's grid system on it.

The problem is that the `col-*` classes floats so we need to add `.clearfix` to the parent container to make it not ignore the content's height. Well, just try to use `.clearfix` inside a table and you'll see that the `:before` and `:after` elements used by the fix gets a unwanted height resulting in some kind of padding in the container.

Here's a little piece of code showing a cell structure with the clearfix bug:

```
<td colspan="4">    
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <input name="name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input name="nickname">
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading an explanation on [how .clearfix works](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/), I've removed some unnecessary stuff and managed to create an alternative class that works inside elements with `display:table;` too:

```
.clearfixfix {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
```

Only tested in chrome for now.